# excel 2013 interior.color "#Value!" error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

When i try to change color of a cell using a function like this:

```
Function abcd()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Function
```

by calling the function from a cell "=abcd()" it returns a "#Value!" error.

but if i use a sub and run it manually (by pressing the run button) it will work fine.

```
Sub abcd()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

but i want call the function from a cell and i dont want to use conditional formatting.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your function 'abcd()' does not return anything. If you want to return something, add "  abcd = return_value " befor 'End Function'.  Assing a valut to name of function is the way to specify return value in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **function** can only return a value to a cell, it cannot change formats.  Use *Conditional Formatting*